# CSS set background image regarding class selector

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to set the background image of a div regarding its class. The web I am developing should show a set of game cards. Each card is contained in a div and have a class like this:

```
<div class="card value suit>
</div>
```

Being the suit and value for instance clubs and five respectively. So for instance, for a div container like this:

```
<div class="card seven clubs>
</div>
```

I wonder if there is a way via CSS to set its background-image to this attribute without writing this for each card:

```
.card.seven.clubs {
    background-image:  url("../../images/seven_clubs.png");
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at SCSS and it's variables. Also check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518374/scss-variable-class-name

Comment: Regardless, **NO**. SCSS will still output the same CSS. SCSS just makes it easier to write.

Comment: i would suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734546/using-html-data-attribute-to-set-css-background-image-url , to use html attributes like `<div class="card" value="07" suit="clubs">` then in css `background: url("../../images/" attr(value) "_" attr(suit) ".png");` but i think you would be better off setting the backgrounds in the inline css `<div class="card" style="background...">`

Comment: background: url("../../images/" attr(value) "_" attr(suit) ".png"); this indeed does not work doesnt it?

Answer (score 0):

you can't really have dinamy classes with css only, you need some form or precompiler such as SASS to to convert from thing like

```
for every number do {
  generate number properties
}
for every suite do {
  generate suite css properties
}
```

to actual css code in the form of

```
.suite1{
  property: value;
}
.suite2{
  property:value
}
.number1{
  property:value
}
```

or you can use Javascript and dynamically set styles on it

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
for (var i = 0; i++; i < cards.length){
  var thisElementClasses = cards[i].classList;
  let imageUrl = '../../images/'+thisElementClasses[0]+'_'+'thisElementClasses[1]'+'.png';
  card[i].style.backgroundImage = imageUrl;
}
```